# mono not load *.so shared library on server-pc

Tags: c#, dll, mono, shared-libraries

- app was complied on windows7, .net4.0
- i put the dll: TECIT.TFORMer.dll in the app file
- test-pc,i386:  [image]
- server-pc,amd64:[image]

  > on test-pc,i debug the app, and got the resut, log:
  >   [image]
  >   but on server-pc, throw exception, log:
  >   [image]

  **why test-pc app :DllImport attempting to load: 'libTFORMer6.so'
  but server-pc app never show the log?**

  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your mono is 64 bit, you can not load a 32 bit library into it.
While the OS usually supports running 32 bit code, it applies to the whole process.
So you should either make a 64 bit library or run 32 bit mono.

Disclaimer: your question wasn't quite clear whether you are trying to use the same library on both systems.

Comment: i used the same library on both systems.

Comment: when i use lib(amd64)erro, when i use x86_64 ok. and this is the page:http://www.tec-it.com/en/download/tformer/unix-linux-mac-os/Download.aspx. if you can hele more, please and thanks!